# Overloaded operator returns reference to base class, how to return a reference to the derived class instead?

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have a base exception class with (amongst others) a streaming operator:

```
Base& Base::operator<<(const std::string& str);
```

This operator returns `*this`.

I have several derived classes that look like:

```
class Derived : public Base { };
```

At some point I create and throw a class derived from Base. Something like:

```
std::string myStr("foo bar");
throw Derived() << myStr;
```

I would like to catch this exception using:

```
try 
{ 
  [...] 
} 
catch(Derived& ex) 
{ 
  [...] 
}
```

What would be the best way of doing so? Is it OK to cast the Base up to Derived before throwing it? Can I change the base class into a template rather than defining these derived classes? [...] ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in `throw` keyword, not in the reference returned. The reference points well to both the base and the derived classes. It is `throw` keyword that uses the declared type rather than the polymorphic type of the object to throw. To throw the polymorphic type of the exception, you can use [Polymorphic Exception C++ idiom](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Polymorphic_Exception). You need to declare a virtual `Raise()` method in the base class, and then override the method in the derived class with implementation `throw *this;`. In that case, in the derived class the declared type of reference `*this` will match its polymorphic type, unless you forget to override `Raise()` method in some derived class.

Answer (score 1):

I would rearrange your code slightly so that the insertion operator is outside any exception classes.

```
class StringBuilder
{
public:
    template<class T>
    StringBuilder& operator<<(const T& t)
    {
        ss_ << t;
        return *this;
    }

    operator std::string() const
    {
        return ss_.str();
    }

private:
    std::stringstream ss_;
};

class Base : public std::runtime_error
{
    using runtime_error::runtime_error;
};

class Derived : public Base
{
    using Base::Base;
};

int main()
{
    try
    {
        throw Derived(StringBuilder() << "hello world");
    }
    catch(const Derived& e)
    {
        std::cout << "Derived\n";
    }
    catch(const Base& e)
    {
        std::cout << "Base\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```